# Combobox change event is firing for any changes in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, worksheet

I tried to have ComboBox in my spreadsheet but it does not work the way I want. The problem I have is that the combobox event (drop down) is triggered for any changes made in the work sheet. for example, I have combobox linked to cell A1, whenever I change the value in H9 cell,  (or any other cells) the dropdown of the combobox is triggered. I want to trigger the combobox drop box only when its linked cell changes, which is A1.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'DROP-DOWN USE CATEGORY BOX ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Dim Use As String
Dim Ind As String
Use = Worksheets("PEC Calculator").Range("B8").Value
Ind = Worksheets("PEC Calculator").Range("B3").Value
If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "UC_List"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim tblA As ListObject
Dim nRows As Long
Dim nCols As Long

Set tblA = Worksheets("PEC Calculator").ListObjects("ATableINPUT")

If tblA.Range(2, 2).Value = "TableA1" Then
    If Range("B4").Value = "Batch" Then
    tblA.Range(3, 2) = 0.000001
    Else
    tblA.Range(3, 2) = 0.000001
    End If
End if
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? any idea?

Comment: Yes. you are right. I forgot to put the line here. I updated the code

Comment: Didn't you copy the events code like they are? Did you write their code in the question?

Comment: I copied my code in the question.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue. Are there any other events that are happening on the sheet that might be causing this behavior?

Comment: No, I just defined the Combobox and link to the  A1. 'UC_list' is a dynamic list.

Comment: Does A1 contain a formula? If the formula recalculates, it triggers a `ComboBox.Change` event even if the calculated result is the same. Some Excel formulas will ask for recalculation after any sheet change. which would explain your observed behaviors.

Comment: Yes. A1 refer to a dynamic list calculated in another sheet. A1 behaves as auto-complete cell.

Comment: Is there any way to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ComboBox.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/change-event) event triggers everytime the `.Value` property changes. The `.LinkedCell` property that you have set to `A1` is causing these events to fire on every sheet change because `A1` contains a formula.

- Some formulas in Excel ask to be recalculated on every sheet change.
- Even if the new value is the same as the old value, it still triggers the `ComboBox.Change` event.

To resolve this issue, I suggest declaring a [Module-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level) variable and using it to save the ComboBox's Value. Module-Level Variables retain their value between executions. This way you can compare the old and new value during each event and only execute your actions when the value has changed.

```vb
Dim CB_Val As Variant
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> CB_Val Then
        CB_Val = Me.ComboBox1.Value
        'DROP-DOWN USE CATEGORY BOX ///////////////
        Dim Use As String
        Dim Ind As String
        Use = Worksheets("PEC Calculator").Range("B8").Value
        Ind = Worksheets("PEC Calculator").Range("B3").Value
        If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
            ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "UC_List"
            Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Much appreciated!